# Uncollapse div automatically on page open

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a link like this

```
<a href="http://192.168.178.165/home/item#145">Item</a>
```

and when I click that link the page opens and gets focused on that item. There is a list of multiple items which are all collapsed with css:

```
.item-hidden {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And when I click on heading that div gets uncollapsed.

Is there a way somehow to automatically uncollapse that div from link when that page is opened?

#### update

This is the function for collapsing and uncollapsing

```
$(function () {
    $(".item-panel").click(function(){
        var itemId = $(this).attr('data-item-id');
        $('#'+itemId).toggleClass('item-hidden');
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes. trigger the function that opens it

Comment: Post the code for the divs, headings and how they get uncollapsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write this on top of your script file outside all other functions

```
var itemId = location.hash;
if($(itemId).length != 0){
  $(itemId).removeClass('item-hidden');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS `:target` pseudo.

Example having `http://192.168.178.165/home/item#145`:

```
<div id="145" class="item">
   <h2>I'm item 145</h2>
   <div class="content">I'm some content</div>
</div>
```

```
.item .content{
  display:none; /* collapse content (Toggles using jQuery anyways) */
}

.item:target .content{ /* If .item is :target, expand it's content! */
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Will it work on page reload ? The anchor tag is redirecting to a new page on click.

Comment: @DanPhilip yes. Download this BIN and test using for example `#146` http://jsbin.com/qicufik/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Poslao sam ti zahtjev. Ima 3 tvoja profila neznam sad koji je pravi

Answer (score 0):

When the page opens/loads invoke the `click` on the item/div header that you want to be expanded.

Comment: So i need to call that function on page open, but how to send the item id how the function knows which one to open?

Comment: which item do you want to open? Maybe first element in a list of `divs`, then you can have a `class` selector on those `divs` and using that class can grab the first div and expand it by invoking click.

Comment: I need to open the item which is in the link from previous page

Comment: can you share the code of the next page, because I see something like `item#145` in the URL, which we can grab easily to identify the item.